# Resizing the winform at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

how to resize a tab control in a winform (C# .Net), controls(inside tabpage) must move  while resizing the form

Comment: What? Move *where*? Spend a little more time writing your questions before clicking "Post".

Answer (score 0):

Set [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)  property of that control. Alternatively you may use [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx)

Anchor - defines a constant space between one or more edges of it's container.

Dock - control borders are docked to its parent control.

Comment: thank you Andrzej Nosal but the control's size must be unchanged and move one below the other while resizing the form

Comment: That's impossible. You need to set either the `Anchor` or `Dock` property of the **`TabControl`**, not the `TabPage`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the Dock property is what you're looking for.
If you put a panel.Dock=Dock.Fill then it will take all the space available.
so when the controls is resized, the panel is too.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of your comment to Andrzej's answer:

> the control's size must be unchanged and move one below the other while resizing the form

**It sounds like what you need is a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx).** Drop one onto your `TabPage`, set its [`FlowDirection` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection.aspx) to [the value of your choice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowdirection.aspx), and place your controls into it. Now, whenever the `TabControl` is resized, the controls it contains will automatically shift positions to fill the space.

Comment: Thank you Cody Gray, need to resize the form as we can see in google page

Comment: @Vishnu: Google page? I'm sorry, but I don't know what you're talking about. Can you provide me with a link?

Comment: www.ggogle.com if u restoredown and try to reduce it the controls moves

Comment: @Vishnu: If you find that answers on Stack Overflow have helped you (or were the best answer to your question), you should accept them by clicking the outline of a checkmark in the left margin next to the answer. It will turn green once you've done this. You can only accept one answer per question, but you can upvote (once you receive enough reputation points) as many as you like.